# 日時を mm/dd hh:mm で表示している箇所で、月が12より大きい場合がある

Tags: バグ, 完了

[image: 質問一覧での一例]

具体例:

https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/10/revisions

誤: `質問日時: 19月30日の9:19`  
正: `質問日時: 9月30日の9:19`